# LaTeX - Cline - Amendment at the right end

Tags: tables

Cline command in connection with a text at the right end. Is this possible?

Concretely, I want to present via the `\cline` command a time bar within `tabular`, which has at its right end a `\triangleright` and the description "Time". The axis intercepts and the other lettering are just in order with the help of other rows.

With regard to the questions:

(1) Yes, it is in connection with `tabular`.
(2) The document class is `article`, and the desired result looks similar to the following:

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----------|>  Time
```

(1) and (2) By the way, I would like to hint at the answer of David Carlisle, which already is a very great progress for solving my difficulty.

To David Carlisle:

I’m grateful to you for your answer containing the necessary program lines. What now still is failing, is that the `\triangleright` and the lettering “Time” are vertically not on the height of the time bar. Is it possible to avoid this optical deficit?

In the meantime I have solved the difficulties with the vertical and the horizontal positioning with the commands `\raisebox` and `\hspace`.

Comment: Does it have to be in conjunction with a `tabular`? Most graphics packages like [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) will be able to present this timeline without problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I do not understand what you want the end result to be. It would be helpful if you could provide a picture of the desired result, or even better provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates what you have tried so far.  This should include the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: @ORgl: If you register, than you will stay in control of your question and can edit it without anyone having to approve your edits. (some mod will need to merge your user accounts – just flag for their assistance).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

spacing could be improved but this might get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zcline{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zzcline\cline}

\def\zzcline#1\cr{#1\smash{\tiny $\triangleright$ time}\cr}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
aa&bbb&ccc&ee&ff\\
\zcline{2-4}
aaa&bbb&ccc&e&fff\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m grateful to You for Your answer containing the necessary program lines. What now still is lacking, is that the triangleright and the lettering “Time” are vertically not on the height of the timebar. Is it possible to avoid this situation?